Top-align fbox in list item
I have an fbox as the content of a list item, and I want the bullet point to be at the top of the box, like it would be for a plain paragraph, but the bullet is vertical-centered on the box. Here's what I have at the moment.
\begin{itemize}
\item
    \fbox{
    \parbox{\linewidth}{
    \textbf{Def:} Let $K/F$ be a finite ext. We say $K/F$ is \textbf{Galois} and $K/F$ is a \textbf{Galois extension} if 
    \[|\Aut(K/F)| = [K:F].\]
    }
    }
\end{itemize}


And what I want is something like this:

Thanks y'all.

Welcome to TSE. Please post a Minimal Working Example, instead of a code snippet.

\parbox[t]{\linewidth}  (although \linewidth is too wide you need to allow for the \fboxsep and \fboxruleeither side, and two spaces within the fbox

@DavidCarlisle that worked, thank you!

You can top align using \parbox[t]{\linewidth} (although \linewidth is too wide you need to allow for the \fboxsep and \fboxrule either side, and two spaces within the fbox.
